# Convert JSON.NET date to jQuery UI Datepicker format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, momentjs

I am serializing and passing a date out of my controller using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and sending it to a jQuery UI Datepicker field. Right now the output is like `"2015-12-05T00:00:00"` and I want it to be in a format of `MM/DD/YYYY`. My output is available via the AJAX returned data object `data.BoardStart` and is being attached to `#BoardStart` but always shows as 12/31/1969.

I've tried moment (and failed) using this code:

```
var BoardStart = data.BoardStart;
$("#BoardStart").val(moment(BoardStart).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library for formatting date, substitute

```
moment(BoardStart).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

with

```
moment(BoardStart, "YYYY-MM-DDhh:mm:ss").format("MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Comment: The ISO format is supported by default, so this shouldn't have made any difference.  See "Supported ISO 8601 strings" under [this part of the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).   Also, you are missing the `T`, but that wouldn't make a difference either.

Answer (score 1):

You can build it like this

```
var date1 = "2015-12-05T00:00:00";
date1.replace('T',' ');
var date2 = new Date(date1);
var yyyy = date2.getFullYear().toString();
var mm = (date2.getMonth()+1).toString();
var dd  = date2.getDate().toString();
var finaldate = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
```

Comment: A couple of issues with this approach: 1) you'd need to zero-pad the mm and dd values.  2) the `Date` object might parse it as UTC instead of local time, which could throw it a day earlier depending on time zone.  moment is much safer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#BoardStart").datepicker("setDate", new Date(data.BoardStart));
```